# Why call javascript behaviour within its own function?

Tags: javascript

Looking at the JavaScript below, what does calling the behaviourName do?

```
  Drupal.behaviors.behaviourName = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $('.someClass', context).once('some-handler').behaviourName(); // what does this do? 
    }
  };
```

I though that the behaviourName was generally used for name spacing. I can see in the site that im working on that the behaviour name is normally called within itself like in this example. What is this for?

Answer (score 3):

You're reading that wrong - the return from `once()` isn't `Drupal.behaviors` (it's a collection of jQuery elements), and `Drupal.behaviors.behaviourName` isn't a function that will do anything by invoking it, anyway. You would need

```
Drupal.behaviors.behaviourName.attach();
```

To get anything meaningful, but that's not synonymous with the code you're referencing.

So that code is **not** calling a *javascript behaviour within its own function*. It's calling a jQuery extension function on the elements returned from `once()`. Most commonly when code needs to do what you're describing in Drupal, you'll see `Drupal.attachBehaviors();` instead.

What you have is a convention used by the developer who wrote the script, nothing more; you'll need to ask them for their motivation for doing so, and how/where they're attaching the `$.fn` functions of the same names as the behaviours.